# Reverting a Python/Cocoa project to use the default OSX 10.5 Python (2.5)

Tags: python, cocoa, xcode, xcodebuild, pyobjc

I have installed the latest MacPython (2.6.2) on my Leopard OS X and started an XCode PyObjC project.

When I finalized the app, I built the release version and sent it to a friend of mine to try if it runs with out of the box. It did not, because it expects the latest Python, as on my computer.

No matter what I tried, I could not find any config file, etc. where I could change this setting to expecting the default Python that came with OS X.

Any and all help will be much appreciated.

Regards,
OA

Comment: What is the exact error message reported on your friend's computer?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling what you now have in /Library/Frameworks (so XCode falls back to the Python in /System/Library/Frameworks) would work but may be considered a bit drastic. [This post](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=377881#6) and its followups have other potentially useful recommendations, the best one being in the followup at the very end -- you can edit the configurations in /Developer/Library/Xcode/Project Templates/Application/ to determine which Python version XCode projects will be using.